# Non-Generic TaskCompletionSource or alternative

Tags: c#, .net, async-await

I'm working with an alert window (Telerik WPF) that is normally displayed asynchronously ( code continues running while it is open) and I want to make it synchronous by using async/await.

I have this working with `TaskCompletionSource` but that class is generic and returns an object like `Task<bool>` when all I want is a plain `Task` with no return value.

```
public Task<bool> ShowAlert(object message, string windowTitle)
{
    var dialogParameters = new DialogParameters { Content = message };

    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
    dialogParameters.Closed += (s, e) => tcs.TrySetResult(true);

    RadWindow.Alert(dialogParameters);

    return tcs.Task;
}
```

The code that calls that method is

```
await MessageBoxService.ShowAlert("The alert text.")
```

How can I return a non-generic Task that functions similarly which I can await until the `dialogParameters.Closed` event fires?  I understand that I could just ignore the `bool` that is being returned in this code.  I am looking for a different solution than that.

Answer (score 112, accepted):

The method can be changed to:

```
public Task ShowAlert(object message, string windowTitle)
```

`Task<bool>` inherits from `Task` so you can return `Task<bool>` while only exposing `Task` to the caller

**Edit:**

I found a Microsoft document, http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=19957, by Stephen Toub titled 'The Task-based Asynchronous pattern' and it has the following excerpt that recommends this same pattern.

> There is no non-generic counterpart to TaskCompletionSource<TResult>.  However, Task<TResult> derives from Task, and thus the generic TaskCompletionSource<TResult> can be used for I/O-bound methods that simply return a Task by utilizing a source with a dummy TResult (Boolean is a good default choice, and if a developer is concerned about a consumer of the Task downcasting it to a Task<TResult>, a private TResult type may be used)

Answer (score 64):

If you don't want to leak information, the common approach is to use `TaskCompletionSource<object>` and complete with a result of `null`. Then just return it as a `Task`.

Answer (score 24):

.NET 5 has a non-generic `TaskCompletionSource`.

It was added in this pull request: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/pull/37452/files#diff-4a72dcb26e2d643c337baef9f64312f3

Answer (score 3):

[Nito.AsyncEx](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx) implements a non-generic `TaskCompletionSource` class, credit to Mr @StephenCleary above.

Comment: It has been removed, found this in the source: The non-generic `TaskCompletionSource` has been removed. Use `TaskCompletionSource<object>` instead.

Answer (score 1):

From @Kevin Kalitowski

> I found a Microsoft document, http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=19957, by Stephen Toub titled 'The Task-based Asynchronous pattern'

There is an example in this document which I think deals with the issue as Kevin points out. This is the example:

```
public static Task Delay(int millisecondsTimeout)
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
    new Timer(self =>
    {
        ((IDisposable)self).Dispose();
        tcs.TrySetResult(true);
    }).Change(millisecondsTimeout, -1);
    return tcs.Task;
}
```

At first I thought it was not good because you can't directly add the "async" modifier to the method without a compilation message. But, if you change the method slightly, the method will compile with async/await:

```
public async static Task Delay(int millisecondsTimeout)
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
    new Timer(self =>
    {
        ((IDisposable)self).Dispose();
        tcs.TrySetResult(true);
    }).Change(millisecondsTimeout, -1);
    await tcs.Task;
}
```

Edit: at first I thought I'd gotten over the hump. But, when I ran the equivalent code in my app, this code just makes the app hang when it gets to await tcs.Task;. So, I still believe that this is a serious design flaw in the async/await c# syntax.